# Is there a fix for missing balloon content for a Google Earth placemark when opened from \\localhost\c$?

Tags: html, kml, google-earth, popup-balloons

Users have a Windows Folder Shortcut with a Target of \\localhost\c$\sub. When any kml or kmz file under that folder opens in Google Earth Pro, a selected placemark displays an empty description balloon. For example* this is how the clubhouse appears
[clubhouse with empty balloon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05kmm.png)
*(from kml reference extended data example at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata)

**EDIT**: Here's [my file](https://app.box.com/s/2mnug02al4nf7f0u8xl0b6nynct65tg2) and here's a [tut file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml) that displays the similar behavior for the placemark.

This is the expected result --
[clubhouse with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucFuZ.png)

This is happening with all files on Google Earth Pro  7.3.3.7786 (64-bit) [Build Date July 21,2020 PM UTC; Renderer OpenGL; Microsoft Windows (6.2.9200.0)] installed on Windows 10 Pro Version 2004, build 19041.746.
**EDIT**: Updated to Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2, build 19042.746, yet problem persists.

I have tried all options in the Google Earth Repair tool, and recreating the windows file association. I tried changing the placemark description HTML from CDATA format to Extended Data pairs. I also tried adding the balloon visibility element to the placemark with as shown in the documentation --
<gx:balloonVisibility>1</gx:balloonVisibility>

The balloon displays properly if the kml or kmz file is opened

1. from a Network Folder mapped as \\localhost\c$\sub, or
2. from the "Local Drive (C:)" subfolder of "This PC"

Since my users will likely open the kml/kmz file from their File Explorer folder shortcut, is there some other way to force the HTML description to display in the balloon when opened that way?

Comment: Would you be able to share your KML/KMZ file, or a sample of one of the placemarks, so we can see what's going on with the balloon content and styles?  That would allow us to help debug.  
If your file is opening from File Explorer, then your file association should be fine.  It would be very strange if this issue only happened by clicking the file in File Explorer, vs using the Open dialog in Earth.  Are you absolutely sure that's the only difference?  
Also, if the balloon is showing up (even empty), then it's almost certainly not an issue with <gx:balloonVisibility>.

Comment: Question edited to add link to file(s).

Comment: @Christiaan Adams You are right strange indeed. More testing shows that the error is caused by the file location being referenced as \\localhost\c$\ not the use of File Explorer. Question updated .